# Searching 1st column's value from 2nd col and returning 3rd col value if match

Tags: excel, duplicates, match, calculated-columns

I have list A which has only Names (60 rows).
Then I have another list B which has Names and also IDs (200 rows).

What I want is to **find match for A list Name in B list to be able to give IDs for A list Name**.
I've tried a number of functions but none of them seem to solve it.

Is this something that has to be done with VBA?

I've tried with different combinations of vlookup,match, iferror etc. but nothing works....

But I got it solved. I needed to use separate sheets for this matching/filtering e.g sheet 1 for A and sheet 2 for B list and then use VSEARCH.

Example

```
A LIST
Name
Name12
...60

B LIST
Name   ID
Name1  123
...300
```

Comment: I think a small example with expected results would help illustrate your query. A little difficult to understand without one.

Comment: An example would certainly help. Is the ID amalgamated with the name is column B?

Comment: Either `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX(array, MATCH(...` with the proper arguments should work.  Configure the arguments according to how your data is set up.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this is how you can get the IDs in column F.

The formula will find the name in column E from range A2 to B14 and return the IDs in column F.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this is what is was trying but it just didn't work and gave unexpected results. When changing into two separate sheets all went well at the first try. Do not know what was going on. I'm using the latest Excel for Mac (15.13.1)

Comment: There must be something went wrong in referencing the cell or a range. Hard to tell without see what actually you have tried.

Comment: I was just like in your example.And I actually spent a while and I mean 45 minutes or so with this at first. Immediately after changing into to two sheet method it worked.

Answer (score 0):

At least for me the solution was to use separate sheets in order to get VSEARCH to work properly. If it is a standard and "by the book" then it should clearly stated somewhere that with vsearch you must use two separate sheet or xls files.